# Linking two small offices

Tags: vpn

I have a task to link two small offices together so internal resources can be shared. More specifically Microsoft's remote desktop is most important thing as 1C bookkeeping software is used on "server" machine and others are connecting to it whit separate accounts whit Remote Desktop. Far as I know VPN is a way to go. Site-to-site might be the best solution, but I can't mess around whit hardware in one of offices. Short about sites:

Site A is office I cant mess around whit and it have the "server" under it.

Site B is where I can change things.

I was thinking about setting up VPN router on site B and connect site A to it. I have tested basic VPN servers like OpenVPN on Ubuntu and setup Mikrotik VPN under My dayjob router, but VPN clients cant see each other and in setup as this, "server" will be client.

Any suggestions about better solution?

Answer (score 2):

### General Answer

To connect two site, **VPN** in any form is the generally accepted solution, there is however not one VPN like the other ^^

### Specific Anwser

In your case, the task look impossible at first, building a site-to-site VPN while not being able to modify one of the site is like building a bridge on the ocean, with no "landing point" how could you expect the vpn to establish ?

Depending on the budget you can look for operators lan-to-lan solution, they will take care of the vpn for you, or you can build vpn based on off-the-shelf black-box, or you can use open-source software solution on commodity hardware (openvpn and the like).

But all thoses solutions expect some network cooperation from both side to be able to setup a working bridge between your two sites.

Comment: I'm new to VPN so i don't know that much, that's why I'm here. Far as My research goes I understand and I agree that situation is problematic. Your suggestion about black-box crossed My mind as one custom build Ubuntu Server is deployed in site B. It have separate wan connection coming to it it could be used in that way, but that server holds mail server for around 10 users and informative home page, I'm worried about loads. How much resources VPN takes? Obvious that VPN traffic will take a big part from internet connection. That server have i3-6100T, 8GB ram, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It's way over sized for any of thoses uses xD

Comment: Its not that bad. :D Server was bought whit expansion idea in future. I have no idea what they will need and I warned that this might be plenty enough, even overkill. I'm continuing research and seems like OpenVPN whit tap might be a way to go.